# Cordova custom plugin with third party native android library not working

Tags: javascript, cordova, android-library

In my cordova project, I need to use native code that scan via scan device on PDA, not by camera. I have working native android project and I changed it to android library project. Then I copied res, src, project.properties and AndroidManifest.xml files into myCordovaPlugin-> src-> android-> LibraryProject.  When I build my cordova app in Ripple, there is no error. But when I build in device, I'm getting this error message. "Error 102 cmd: Command failed with exit code 8". I tried some solutions that I found online. But still the error is there.
Please help me. I'm very new to cordova and this is my first applicaton. I'm very appreciate any help. Thank you.

Here is Scanner.java.

```
    package com.customplugin.barcodescanner;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;

import android.util.Log;


public class Scanner extends CordovaPlugin {
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final String SCAN_INTENT =                   com.adlink.sample.SDK.SCAN;

    private CallbackContext callbackContext;


    public Scanner() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        this.callbackContext = callbackContext;

        if (action.equals(SCAN)) {
            scan(args);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}


public void scan(JSONArray args) {
        Intent intentScan = new Intent(SCAN_INTENT);
        intentScan.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

        // add config as intent extras
        if(args.length() > 0) {

            JSONObject obj;
            JSONArray names;
            String key;
            Object value;

            for(int i=0; i<args.length(); i++) {

                try {
                    obj = args.getJSONObject(i);
                } catch(JSONException e) {
                    Log.i("CordovaLog", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    continue;
                }

                names = obj.names();
                for(int j=0; j<names.length(); j++) {
                    try {
                        key = names.getString(j);
                        value = obj.get(key);

                        if(value instanceof Integer) {
                            intentScan.putExtra(key, (Integer)value);
                        } else if(value instanceof String) {
                            intentScan.putExtra(key, (String)value);
                        }

                    } catch(JSONException e) {
                        Log.i("CordovaLog", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        // avoid calling other phonegap apps
        intentScan.setPackage(this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName());

        this.cordova.startActivityForResult((CordovaPlugin) this, intentScan, REQUEST_CODE);
    }

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    obj.put(TEXT, intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));
                    obj.put(FORMAT, intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT"));
                    obj.put(CANCELLED, false);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "This should never happen");
                }
                //this.success(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, obj), this.callback);
                this.callbackContext.success(obj);
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    obj.put(TEXT, "");
                    obj.put(FORMAT, "");
                    obj.put(CANCELLED, true);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "This should never happen");
                }
                //this.success(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, obj), this.callback);
                this.callbackContext.success(obj);
            } else {
                //this.error(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR), this.callback);
                this.callbackContext.error("Unexpected error");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initiates a barcode encode.
     *
     * @param type Endoiding type.
     * @param data The data to encode in the bar code.
     */
    public void encode(String type, String data) {
        Intent intentEncode = new Intent(ENCODE_INTENT);
        intentEncode.putExtra(ENCODE_TYPE, type);
        intentEncode.putExtra(ENCODE_DATA, data);
        // avoid calling other phonegap apps
        intentEncode.setPackage(this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName());

        this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intentEncode);
    }
}
```

And here is Scanner.js.

```
    cordova.define('cordova/plugin/Scanner', function(require, exports, module) {    

var exec = require("cordova/exec");

/**
 * Empty constructor
 */
var customScanner = function() {
};
customScanner.prototype.scan=
function (successCallback, errorCallback) {
    exec(successCallback,
        errorCallback,
             "Scanner",
             "scan",
             []);
}
module.exports = new customScanner();
```

});

Here is plugin call from onDeviceReady function of index.js.

```
    var Scanner = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/Scanner");
Scanner.scan();
```

Here is my Native ScannerActivity.java.

```
    package com.mypackage.sample.SDK;

import com.mypackage.sample.SDK.ENGINE;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ScanActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    private static FakeR fakeR;
    private static final String TAG = "ScanActivity";

    private static final int DIALOG_WAITTING = 2;

    private BroadcastReceiver m_msgReceiver = null;
    private DBaseUtil m_db = null;
    private SparseArray<Boolean> m_engineSupported = null;

    private TextView m_btnScan = null;
    private RadioButton m_rbBarcode1D = null;
    private RadioButton m_rbBarcodeCCD = null;
    private TextView m_scanSymbology = null;
    private TextView m_scanSize = null;
    private TextView m_scanValue = null;
    private TextView m_scanElapse = null;
    private boolean m_inProgress = false;
    private boolean m_scanStarted = false;
    private int m_nextEngine = ADMSG.ENGINE.None;
    private ProgressDialog m_dlgProgress = null;
    private boolean m_showMoreInfo = false;
    private long m_scanStartTime = 0;
    private int m_scanMode = ADMSG.SCANMODE.ONETIME;
    private int m_scanKeycode = -1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        fakeR = new FakeR(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(fakeR.getId("layout", "scan_main"));

        m_db = new DBaseUtil(this);
        m_engineSupported = new SparseArray<Boolean>();
        decideScanEngine();

        boolean Barcode1D_enabled = engineEnabled(ADMSG.ENGINE.Barcode_1D);
        boolean BarcodeCCD_enabled = engineEnabled(ADMSG.ENGINE.Barcode_CCD);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate - Barcode_1D="+Barcode1D_enabled+", Barcode_CCD="+BarcodeCCD_enabled);

        if(!Barcode1D_enabled && !BarcodeCCD_enabled)
        {
            showDialog_noSupportedEngine();
        }

        m_btnScan = (TextView)findViewById(fakeR.getId("id", "btnScan"));
        m_btnScan.setOnClickListener(this);
        //m_btnScan.setOnKeyListener(this);
        m_rbBarcode1D = setEngineSwitch(fakeR.getId("id", "Reader_Barcode_1D"), Barcode1D_enabled);
        m_rbBarcodeCCD = setEngineSwitch(fakeR.getId("id", "Reader_Barcode_CCD"), BarcodeCCD_enabled);
        m_scanKeycode = getBgScanKeycode();
        //Log.d(TAG, "onCreate - scanKeycode="+m_scanKeycode);

        int currentEngine = checkAndCorrectEngine(m_db.getCurrentEngine());
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate - currentEngine="+currentEngine);
        switch(currentEngine)
        {
            case ADMSG.ENGINE.Barcode_1D:   m_rbBarcode1D.setChecked(true); break;
            case ADMSG.ENGINE.Barcode_CCD:  m_rbBarcodeCCD.setChecked(true);    break;
        }

        m_scanSymbology = (TextView)findViewById(fakeR.getId("id", "scan_symbology"));
        //m_scanSymbology.setVisibility((m_rbBarcodeCCD.isChecked())?(View.GONE):(View.VISIBLE));

        if(m_showMoreInfo)
        {
            m_scanSize = (TextView)findViewById(fakeR.getId("id", "scan_size"));
            m_scanSize.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            m_scanElapse = (TextView)findViewById(fakeR.getId("id", "scan_elapse"));
            m_scanElapse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        m_scanValue = (TextView)findViewById(fakeR.getId("id", "scan_value"));
        m_scanValue.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestart()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRestart");
        super.onRestart();
        m_scanSymbology.setText(null);
        m_scanValue.setText(null);
        if(m_scanSize != null)
        {
            m_scanSize.setText(null);
        }
        if(m_scanElapse != null)
        {
            m_scanElapse.setText(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();

        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        if(pref != null)
        {
            m_scanMode = (pref.getBoolean("_System_ScanMode_Continuous_", false))?(ADMSG.SCANMODE.CONTINUOUS):(ADMSG.SCANMODE.ONETIME);
        }

        switch(m_db.getCurrentEngine())
        {
            case ADMSG.ENGINE.Barcode_1D:   m_rbBarcode1D.setChecked(true); break;
            case ADMSG.ENGINE.Barcode_CCD:  m_rbBarcodeCCD.setChecked(true);    break;
        }

        disableBgScanMode();
        enableFgScanMode();
        registerMessageReceivers();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
        unregisterMessageReceivers();
        disableFgScanMode();
        enableBgScanMode();
        setScanButtonState(false);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if(keyCode == m_scanKeycode)
        {
            onClick(m_btnScan);
            return(true);
        }
        return(super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if(view == m_btnScan)
        {
            if(m_inProgress)
            {
                if(m_scanMode == ADMSG.SCANMODE.CONTINUOUS)
                {
                    stopScan();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                startScan();
            }
        }
        else if(view == m_rbBarcode1D)
        {
            changeEngine(ADMSG.ENGINE.Barcode_1D);
        }
        else if(view == m_rbBarcodeCCD)
        {
            changeEngine(ADMSG.ENGINE.Barcode_CCD);
        }
    }

    private void decideScanEngine()
    {
        boolean enable_1D = m_db.getEngineSupported(ADMSG.ENGINE.Barcode_1D);
        boolean enable_CCD = m_db.getEngineSupported(ADMSG.ENGINE.Barcode_CCD);

        m_engineSupported.put(ADMSG.ENGINE.Barcode_1D, enable_1D);
        m_engineSupported.put(ADMSG.ENGINE.Barcode_CCD, enable_CCD);
        int currentEngine = m_db.getCurrentEngine();
        Log.d(TAG, "decideScanEngine - currentEngine="+currentEngine);
        if(!isValidEngine(currentEngine))
        {
            m_db.setCurrentEngine(checkAndCorrectEngine(currentEngine));
        }
    }

    private boolean engineEnabled(int id)
    {
        return(m_engineSupported.get(id));
    }

    private boolean isValidEngine(int engine)
    {
        return((engine == ENGINE.Barcode_1D) || (engine == ENGINE.Barcode_CCD));
    }

    private int checkAndCorrectEngine(int engine)
    {
        int validEngine = engine;
        /*
        if(!isValidEngine(validEngine))
        {
            validEngine = m_db.getCurrentEngine();
        }
        */

        if(!isValidEngine(validEngine))
        {
            if(engineEnabled(ADMSG.ENGINE.Barcode_CCD))
            {
                validEngine = ADMSG.ENGINE.Barcode_CCD;
            }
            else if(engineEnabled(ADMSG.ENGINE.Barcode_1D))
            {
                validEngine = ADMSG.ENGINE.Barcode_1D;
            }
            else
            {
                validEngine = ADMSG.ENGINE.None;
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "checkAndCorrectEngine - validEngine="+validEngine);
        return(validEngine);
    }

    private RadioButton setEngineSwitch(int resId, boolean enabled)
    {
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)findViewById(resId);
        if(rb != null)
        {
            rb.setOnClickListener(this);
            if(!enabled)
            {
                rb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
        return(rb);
    }

    private void registerMessageReceivers()
    {
        if(m_msgReceiver == null)
        {
            m_msgReceiver = new MessageReceiver();
        }

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ADMSG.ACTION.OBTAIN_SCAN_DATA);
        filter.addAction(ADMSG.ACTION.ENGINE_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(m_msgReceiver, filter);
    }

    private void unregisterMessageReceivers()
    {
        if(m_msgReceiver != null)
        {
            unregisterReceiver(m_msgReceiver);
        }
    }

    private class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive - action="+action);
            if(ADMSG.ACTION.OBTAIN_SCAN_DATA.equals(action))
            {
                String value = intent.getStringExtra(ADMSG.KEY.SCAN.VALUE);
                String symbology = intent.getStringExtra(ADMSG.KEY.SCAN.SYMBOLOGY);
                boolean finished = intent.getBooleanExtra(ADMSG.KEY.SCAN.FINISHED, true);
                Log.d(TAG, "\tvalue="+value);
                m_scanSymbology.setText(symbology);
                m_scanValue.setText(value);
                m_scanValue.scrollTo(0, 0);

                if(m_scanSize != null)
                {
                    int dataCnt = (value != null)?(value.length()):(0);
                    m_scanSize.setText(String.format("%d", dataCnt));
                }

                if(m_scanElapse != null)
                {
                    long elapse = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - m_scanStartTime;
                    m_scanElapse.setText(String.format("%dms", elapse));
                }
                setScanButtonState(!finished);
            }
            else if(ADMSG.ACTION.ENGINE_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action))
            {
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                if(extras == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                int currentEngine = m_db.getCurrentEngine();
                int state = extras.getInt(ADMSG.KEY.ENGINE.STATE);
                boolean engineChanged = extras.getBoolean(ADMSG.KEY.ENGINE.CHANGED);
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive - ENGINE_STATE_CHANGED - state="+state+", engineChanged="+engineChanged);
                if(state == ADMSG.ENGINE.STATE.STARTED)
                {
                    showInitEngineProgress(false);
                }
                else if((state == ADMSG.ENGINE.STATE.STARTING) ||
                        (state == ADMSG.ENGINE.STATE.STOPPING))
                {
                }
                else if(state == ADMSG.ENGINE.STATE.STOPPED)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "\tSTOPPED - engine: "+currentEngine+" -> "+m_nextEngine);
                    if((m_nextEngine == currentEngine) ||
                       !isValidEngine(m_nextEngine))
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    m_db.setCurrentEngine(checkAndCorrectEngine(currentEngine));
                    m_nextEngine = ADMSG.ENGINE.None;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void setScanMode(boolean bgScan, boolean enable)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "setScanMode - bgScan="+bgScan+", enable="+enable);
        Intent in = new Intent();
        in.setAction((bgScan)?(ADMSG.ACTION.BGSCAN_MODE):(ADMSG.ACTION.FGSCAN_MODE));
        in.putExtra(ADMSG.KEY.SCAN.COMMAND, (enable)?(ADMSG.CMD.ENABLE):(ADMSG.CMD.DISABLE));
        in.putExtra(ADMSG.KEY.REQUESTER.PACKAGE, getPackageName());
        in.putExtra(ADMSG.KEY.REQUESTER.CLASS, getClass().getName());
        in.putExtra(ADMSG.KEY.SCAN.MODE, m_scanMode);
        if(m_scanMode == ADMSG.SCANMODE.CONTINUOUS)
        {
            in.putExtra(ADMSG.KEY.SCAN.OPT.CS.FIXED_PERIOD, false);
            in.putExtra(ADMSG.KEY.SCAN.OPT.CS.IGNORE_SAME_ONE, true);
            in.putExtra(ADMSG.KEY.SCAN.OPT.CS.STOP_IF_SUCCESS, true);
            in.putExtra(ADMSG.KEY.SCAN.OPT.CS.TIME_INTERVAL, 1500);
        }
        //in.putExtra(ADMSG.KEY.BGSCAN_KEYCODE, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
        sendBroadcast(in);
    }

    private void enableBgScanMode()
    {
        setScanMode(true, true);
    }

    private void disableBgScanMode()
    {
        setScanMode(true, false);
    }

    private void enableFgScanMode()
    {
        setScanMode(false, true);
    }

    private void disableFgScanMode()
    {
        setScanMode(false, false);
    }

    private void startScan()
    {
        m_scanSymbology.setText(null);
        m_scanValue.setText(null);
        if(m_scanSize != null)
        {
            m_scanSize.setText(null);
        }
        if(m_scanElapse != null)
        {
            m_scanElapse.setText(null);
        }
        setScanButtonState(true);
        sendScanCommand(this, -1, ADMSG.CMD.START);
        m_scanStartTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    }

    private void stopScan()
    {
        sendScanCommand(this, -1, ADMSG.CMD.STOP);
    }

    private void changeScanEngine(Context context, int engine)
    {
        //Log.d(TAG, "chageEngine - engine="+engine);
        Intent in = new Intent();
        in.setAction(ADMSG.ACTION.ENGINE_CHANGE);
        in.putExtra(ADMSG.KEY.ENGINE.ID, engine);
        context.sendBroadcast(in);
    }

    private void sendScanCommand(Context context, int engine, String cmd)
    {
        //Log.d(TAG, "startScanService - engine="+engine+", cmd="+cmd);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString(ADMSG.KEY.SCAN.COMMAND, cmd);
        extras.putInt(ADMSG.KEY.SCAN.ENGINE, engine);
        sendScanCommand(context, extras);
    }

    private void sendScanCommand(Context context, Bundle extras)
    {
        Intent in = new Intent();
        in.setAction(ADMSG.ACTION.SCAN);
        in.putExtras(extras);
        context.sendBroadcast(in);
    }

    private void enableScanButton(boolean enabled)
    {
        //Log.d(TAG, "> enableScanButton - m_scanStarted="+m_scanStarted);
        m_inProgress = !enabled;
        Resources rcs = getResources();
        if(m_scanMode == ADMSG.SCANMODE.CONTINUOUS)
        {
            int txtRes = (enabled)?(fakeR.getId("string", "txt_Scan")):(fakeR.getId("string", "txt_Stop"));
            m_btnScan.setText(txtRes);
        }
        else
        {
            int txtColorRes = (enabled)?(fakeR.getId("color", "text_color_tab_checked")):(fakeR.getId("color", "text_color_tab_unchecked"));
            m_btnScan.setTextColor(rcs.getColor(txtColorRes));
            m_btnScan.setEnabled(enabled);
        }
    }

    private void setScanButtonState(boolean pressed)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, ">> setScanButtonState - pressed="+pressed);
        m_scanStarted = pressed;
        enableScanButton(!pressed);
    }

    private void changeEngine(int engine)
    {
        int currentEngine = m_db.getCurrentEngine();
        Log.d(TAG, "changeEngine - engine: "+currentEngine+" -> "+engine);
        if(engine == currentEngine)
        {
            return;
        }

        showInitEngineProgress(true);
        m_scanSymbology.setText(null);
        m_scanValue.setText(null);
        if(m_scanSize != null)
        {
            m_scanSize.setText(null);
        }
        if(m_scanElapse != null)
        {
            m_scanElapse.setText(null);
        }

        changeScanEngine(this, engine);
        m_nextEngine = engine;
    }

    private void showInitEngineProgress(boolean show)
    {
        if(show)
        {
            enableScanButton(false);
            showDialog(DIALOG_WAITTING);
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "showInitEngineProgress - m_dlgProgress="+m_dlgProgress);
        if(m_dlgProgress != null)
        {
            m_dlgProgress.dismiss();
            //m_dlgProgress = null;
        }

        if(!m_scanStarted)
        {
            enableScanButton(true);
        }
    }

    private int getBgScanKeycode()
    {
        try
        {
            return(Integer.valueOf(m_db.getBgScanKeycode()));
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "getBgScanKeycode - "+e.toString());
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "getBgScanKeycode - "+e.toString());
        }
        return(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
    {
        switch(id)
        {
            case DIALOG_WAITTING:
            {
                String msg = getResources().getString(fakeR.getId("string", "txt_Engine_initializing"));
                if(m_dlgProgress == null)
                {
                    m_dlgProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
                    m_dlgProgress.setIndeterminate(true);
                    m_dlgProgress.setCancelable(false);
                }
                m_dlgProgress.setMessage(msg);
                return(m_dlgProgress);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(fakeR.getId("menu", "settings_menu"), menu);

        MenuItem item = null;
        item = menu.getItem(0);
        item.setIcon(fakeR.getId("drawable", "ic_menu_preferences"));
        item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener()
        {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)
            {
                Intent preferences = new Intent();
                preferences.setClass(ScanActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(preferences);
                return(true);
            }
        });

        return(true);
    }

    private void showDialog_noSupportedEngine()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        //builder.setTitle(R.string.txt_ResetToDefault);
        builder.setMessage(fakeR.getId("string", "txt_NoAnyValidScanEngine"));
        builder.setPositiveButton(fakeR.getId("string", "txt_OK"), null);
        builder.show().setOnDismissListener(m_dlgResetDismissListener);
    }

    OnDismissListener m_dlgResetDismissListener = new OnDismissListener()
    {
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)
        {
            finish();
        }
    };
}
```